# how would I convert this block of CSS to LESS using regex?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, replace, less

I'm refactoring a bunch of CSS (10,000+ lines), and rather than manually converting line by line, from this:

```
-webkit-transition: .1s linear all;
   -moz-transition: .1s linear all;
        transition: .1s linear all;
```

into this:

```
 .transition(.1s linear all);
```

Is there a way to speed this up with regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how variable the data is, but this is a good start:

```
/(?:\s*(?:-(?:webkit|moz)-)?transition:\s*\.1s linear all;\n)+/
```

If the values are variable, substitute whatever pattern matches your data.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do to aid the conversion is to use a CSS parser to read the CSS, then write your own methods to emit LESS code. [Here is one such parser for Java](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/).

I don't understand why you would need this though. Why don't you just keep the old CSS, and only write new stylesheets in LESS?

But either way, I don't think regex is the best option for this task, since the CSS has to be written in a very specific way for that to work, which is probably not the case for more than 10000 lines of CSS.

Also, you can use [this converter](http://css2less.cc/). It won't do the type of conversion you're referring to though.

Comment: actually I use tools like css lint and recess (as grunt tasks) to find inconsistencies, debug and normalize my css. this resolves the issue you're speaking of

Answer (score 0):

I'd first remove all prefixed ones (http://refiddle.com/2t4) and then replace the unprefixed with the mixin (http://refiddle.com/2t5).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the editor you are using would support find-replace in regex.
(I tried the following steps in Eclipse IDE)

Step 1 : Find ".*-webkit-.*" and replace with blank
Step 2 : Find ".*-moz-.*" and replace with blank
Step 3 : Find "(transition):(.*);" and replace with ".$1($2);"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

with open('/tmp/test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(r'(.*)(transition):\s*(.*);', line)
        if m:
            print(".%s(%s);" % (m.group(2), m.group(3)))
```